# Are titles, labels and other UI-related things should be included in domain model?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am confused about how to treat strictly UI-related things, that won't be used in the business logic in the domain model: how to properly store them in the database?

If for example I have an aggregate which is an entity and the main purpose of this model is to do something with an important thing, should I include a title in the model even though it does not contribute to the business logic in any way? Does it matter if I want to store the title in the same table I store other data for my entity (e.g. important things)?

```
@Entity
MyAggregate:
    id: ID
    title: str
    importantThing: ImportantThing

    def doSomethingWithImportantThing():
        ...
```

And if I don't include a title in the model, then how to properly store it using `Repository` pattern? If I keep the title within my model my Repository could look like so:

```
@Repository
MyAggregateRepository:

    def create(myAggregate: MyAggregate):
        ...
```

What would happen to repository if I remove title from the model? Should it transform like so:

```
@Repository
MyAggregateRepository:

    def create(myAggregate: MyAggregate, title: str):
        ...
```

Comment: Title or label is part of your domain model, despite they don't contribute to any business logic, but they are essential parts of your domain and, it seems to me that they exactly should be in the domain model and they should persist with the whole object in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that are purely UI-related typically don't belong in the domain unless the domain is related to managing UI-related items, such as in the case of a localisation domain.

Data that belongs in the domain would stay in the domain.  For instance, if there is a comment on an `AccountTransaction`, or some such, then that would be in the language used by the users of the system and not something that one could localize.  However, if that transaction has a `Type` indicator that is either `Debit` or `Credit` then you wouldn't want to necessarily use a string representation but rather codify that; even if the "code" is `Debit` and `Credit` or `Dr`/`Cr`.  However, the front-end would use some l10n or i18n mechanism to display the text for the `Type` in the relevant language.

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Comment: In some domains translations are somewhat core though. e.g. At work we must always support the two official languages in all email communications, even for user-submitted content so translations becomes a primary domain concern. A user can't submit communications for publishing without providing French & English contents.

Comment: @plalx, those scenarios do pop up.  In these circumstances the domain has elements of localisation built in.  On a previous contract (late 90's) the life insurance company I worked for required all quotations be in Afrikaans and English and we had the clauses in both languages and then built up the `xml` using the relevant clauses and then created `html` quotes using `xslt`.  As per usual there isn't a one size fits all.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is to keep only things that are necessary for making decisions and protecting invariants inside the aggregate state. Otherwise, aggregates get polluted by alien concerns and convert to a messy one-to-one representation of an over-growing database table or document.

As any rule, it has exceptions. I don't think it's a good idea going overboard from the start and splitting the entity prematurely.

However, if you feel that things get messy and you can see patterns that a group of fields are used in a group of functions, while another group of fields is solely used in a different set of functions, you might get an idea that your aggregate deserves splitting.

The repository pattern is largely relevant for executing commands. Its main purpose is to handle the aggregate persistence. When implementing queries, consider using CQRS and write queries that you need to write, it doesn't have to be the repository that handles queries. Queries are also idempotent and have no side effect (except the performance), so it is rather safe not to think about the domain model as such when writing queries. It's better to name your queries using the Ubiquitous Language though.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `title` within the bounds of your model. There are a few reasons for this.

1. The utility of `title` is kept within the bounds of the model itself, since it does not serve any other purpose in the domain layer.  It serves as "identity" that is merely local to the model itself, and then gets surfaced in the UI.
2. The `title` is not necessary for creating the aggregate, since it has no business logic intent. If it did, it would represent a tighter coupling between the model and the creation of the aggregate, which is typically undesirable.
3. `title` seems to be an aggregate invariant that you'd only want the aggregate root to be concerned with, and not a concern from a perspective of external access or creation.

Ultimately, this keeps your design cleaner.